How to clear gpu memory used by doctr model
I am using doctr for ocr purpose.. and doctr model is running in gpu so after me ocr work is done still it is there loaded in gpu memory.
I am trying to clear gpu memory using
with torch.no_grad(): torch.cuda.empty_cache()
but nothing is working..
Is there any other way to clear gpu memory without killing process using PID
I wanted to perform ocr on image using doctr
